# Using Gmail for Rails App advisable?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, actionmailer, newsletter, mailer

I am currently building a crowdfunding web application with Rails and in order to send registration confirmations, password resets or just newsletters I need a mail service.
Currently I am using a regular Gmail account, is doing so advisable? And to which service should I switch once business gets going?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found using GMail to be fairly reliable. But you do need to be aware of throttling. This probably won't be a problem for your registration confirmations or password resets... but may be someday for your newsletters. I forget the specifics, but if you send out more than about one thousand emails per hour (see link in @Vinay's answer for specifics) they start to get throttled -- which lasts for a period of tiem during which any emails sent simply don't get sent.

Despite GMail's decent reliability, you should consider using a resque, skidekiq, or delayed-job service for the actual sending of the emails. This is jsut a good policy for all external services and GMail is no different, in the end. Using a background job for your mail sender allows you to retry an email send until it works. This helps when either the Gmail SMTP service goes down or when you have a bug in your email sending code.

The question about what service to switch to when you outgrow GMail is very much a matter of opinion. Which is the type of question we try to avoid on Stack Overflow (and the reason why your question has a close vote on it already).

Answer (score 2):

It's fine as long as you don't have too many mails to send out. Gmail has limits on the amount of mail that you can send and receive.

You can find it here: https://support.google.com/a/answer/166852?hl=en

Other than the limits, there is not much of a problem using Gmail. I can't answer the next part of your question unfortunately as I don't have much of an experience in that area.

Comment: +1 for link on throttling limits

Answer (score 0):

I am a big fan of SendGrid, especially if you are are running on heroku. It is simple to add to a rails app on heroku.  https://addons.heroku.com/sendgrid

It will most likely be free when you launch, the free version supports up to 200 emails/day (if you get beyond that, then you are doing well and can afford to pay for it).  It also some nice tools that help you identify which emails aren't being delivered and why.